# How to send Bearer token in header of a websocket request

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I want to send the authorization bearer token in the header of websocket. Is this possible? How can we do this in Go?
I am using gorilla/websocket.

Comment: See here on how to send your own header during the WebSocket initial HTTP handshake -  [Authenticating WebSocket Connections via HTTP Middleware - Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52807735/authenticating-websocket-connections-via-http-middleware-golang)

Answer (score 0):

i do this for socketIO and it's successfully worked.
U should send Authorization in header like `Bearer TOKEN` and then in ur routing use the JWTCheck middleware like below:

```
router.Use(middleware.JWTAccess())

router.GET("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
router.POST("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
router.StaticFS("/public", http.Dir("../asset"))
```